# Calculating dialog units on lfMessageFont - Buttons too big, Segoe UI 1pt too large

Tags: c, winapi, fonts

I'm trying to create pushbuttons matching the style of those in default message boxes and I've been told that using `SystemParametersInfo` I can retrieve `lfMessagefont` which should correspond to the font I'm looking for. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here are the functions used to retrieve the font and to create the buttons:

```
HFONT CreateDefaultUIFont() 
{
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncInfo;
    ncInfo.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncInfo, 0);
    return CreateFontIndirect(&ncInfo.lfMessageFont);
}

SIZE GetBaseUnits(HWND hWnd, HFONT hFont) 
{
    TCHAR szText[] = TEXT("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    HDC   hDC;
    HFONT hFt;
    SIZE  size;
    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
    hFt = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
    GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, szText, 52, &size);
    SelectObject(hDC, hFt);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    size.cx = (size.cx / 26 + 1) / 2;
    return size;
}

HWND CreateButton(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hParent, HFONT hFont, PTSTR szText, int xPos, int yPos)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    SIZE size;
    hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), szText, WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 0, 0, hParent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, FALSE);
    size = GetBaseUnits(hWnd, hFont);
    MoveWindow(hWnd, xPos, yPos, MulDiv(50, size.cx, 4), MulDiv(14, size.cy, 8), TRUE);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    return hWnd;
}
```

And here's the rest of the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    static HINSTANCE   hInstance;
    static HWND        hCtl[2];
    static HFONT       hFont;
    static HDC         hDC;
    static PAINTSTRUCT paint;
    static RECT        rect;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE);
        // hFont = GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
        hFont = CreateDefaultUIFont();
        // hFont = GetStockObject(DEVICE_DEFAULT_FONT);
        hCtl[0] = CreateButton(hInstance, hWnd, hFont, TEXT("OK"), 15, 15);
        hCtl[1] = CreateButton(hInstance, hWnd, hFont, TEXT("Cancel"), 15, 50);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paint);
        SaveDC(hDC);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
        DrawText(hDC, TEXT("Failed to register the window class"), -1, &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        RestoreDC(hDC, -1);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &paint);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) 
{
    const TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("Window");
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASS    wndclass;
    RECT        rect;
    DWORD       dwStyle;
    LONG        nWidth, nHeight;

    wndclass.style         = CS_OWNDC;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed to register the window class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }

    rect.left   = 0;
    rect.top    = 0;
    rect.right  = 480 - 1;
    rect.bottom = 360 - 1;
    dwStyle     = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);

    AdjustWindowRect(&rect, dwStyle, FALSE);

    nWidth  = rect.right - rect.left + 1;
    nHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top + 1;

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, szAppName, dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        nWidth, nHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed to register the window class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

This is how it looks on Windows 10 19043. The font is Segoe UI as it should be except 1pt too big

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Here's how it looks when I use `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`. The size of the buttons is correct but they use Tahoma at 8pt

[image: 4]
[image: 3]

Is there any way to obtain the fonts used in message boxes that would work across different Windows versions?

Comment: Is your program [marked as DPI-aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)? Are you running the program on a display where the DPI scaling factor is different from 100%?

Comment: @IInspectable 100%, it wasn't marked

Comment: If you want pixel-perfect accuracy then you would probably want to mark your program as being DPI-aware, making sure that it actually is.

Comment: It seems there is no problem when using `CW_USEDEFAULT` for `nWidth` and `nHeight` in `CreateWindow`. Perhaps the coordinate mapping has been changed.

Comment: I'll admit tl;dr here but "The Default Message Box Font" *IS* Segoe UI 9pt. Not 8pt.